# copy timeval member variables to integer variable

Tags: c++

I need represent `timeval` structure using two `integer` parameters p1 and p2.
I have copied `tv_sec` to p1 and `tv_usec` to p2.
In 32 bit (centos) `sizeof(long) = sizeof(int)` hence I was able to do above said thing.

But in 64 bit system, (sizeof(tv_sec) = 8).

In 64 bit system how can I assign this `tv_sec` to p1 and p2 as that of 32 bit sytem ?

My code is given below,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  struct timeval mytime;

  gettimeofday(&mytime, NULL);

  cout << "tv_sec_1 :  " << mytime.tv_sec << endl;
  cout << "tv_usec_1 : " << mytime.tv_usec << endl;

  int p1 = mytime.tv_sec;
  int p2 = mytime.tv_usec;

}
```

I need pass these timeval info using two free integer variables in the structure
through which output is passed to calling function. My aim is not to modify result structure.

Comment: I am puzzled. `gettimeofday()` **tv_usec value is always zero.**. No matter what size the chances of tv_usec being 0 all the time is not probable. Are you absolutely sure you called `gettimeofday(&mytime, NULL);` before accessing `mytime` in that case. There seems like a coding bug at play here beyond what you are showing in the sample you provided.

Comment: sorry, tv_usec value is not always 0, there was bug in my code

Comment: `tv_usec` is microseconds so will be a number from 0 to 999,999. That should fit in an int no problem. If `tv_sec` is stored as signed 32bit integer it can be as high as to 2^31-1 (2147483647).  This poses a problem for dates after `2038-01-19 3:14:07 UTC` as it will become a negative number and wrap back to the end of the year 1901. If you don't care about things working beyond 2038-01-19 then storing in an `int` should work.

Comment: Thanks, Now I got answer for my doubt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of `tv_sec` and `tv_usec` can change depending on the system you are on. To avoid that you should not be using `int` to store their values. You should use the appropriate type - namely `time_t` and `suseconds_t` .

Your code should be:

```
time_t p1 = mytime.tv_sec;
suseconds_t p2 = mytime.tv_usec;
```

Information on this can be found in the man and info pages. This [link](http://rabbit.eng.miami.edu/info/functions/time.html#time_t) has information on using time functions properly. In particular they have this to say about `time_t` vs `int`:

> Is exactly identical to "int" in behaviour. You may assign int values
>          to a time_t variable, and vice-versa, and print time_t values using
>          the %d format, and everything.
>          In the future, either time_t will cease to be identical to int, or
>          the meaning of "int" will change from 4-byte-integer to 8-byte-integer

I amended my original answer to be more complete/correct thanks to a comment by Mike Seymour.

Comment: `time_t` isn't necessarily suitable for microseconds either, which is why it has a different type `suseconds_t` within the `timeval`.

Comment: I have project, in that result is passed out through a structure. There are some integer parameters which are unused in the result structure. My aim is to pass this timeval using these unused integers, Without modifying the result structure. In the above case p1 and p2 are the unused integer parameters